# Single Node.js/Mongoose stream from multiple unrelated MongoDB collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, coinbase-api, node-streams

I'm collecting a large amount of data coming from a market data websocket stream. I'm collecting 2 different types of events from this single stream that are to be stored with event date/time and have no parent/child database relation. They're being stored their own respective MongoDB collections due to the difference in data structures.

Once a certain amount of data has been stored (100k+ events), I will be running analysis on the events, but I'd like to do so in a fashion where I'm simulating the original single stream of events by time (not processing both collection streams individually).

What I'd like to be able to do is make a single query from Mongoose, if possible, that joins both collections, sorts by date, and outputs as a stream for memory-saving purposes. So, performance is important in this case due to the number of events.

All answers I've seen when searching for a solution are regarding a parent/child aggregation of some sort, but since this isn't a user/userData-related segment of an application I'm having trouble finding an answer.

Also, storing the data in 2 separate collections seems necessary since their fields are all different except for `time`. But... would there be more pros than cons to keep these events in a single collection, if it eliminates the need for this type of solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data structure reasoning is slightly inverted. Mongodb is schemaless and it's natural to have documents with different structure in the same collection.

It makes it easy to collect and analyse data but cause problems on application level since devs cannot rely on data structure and have to validate it on each data retrieval.

Mongoose aims to solve this problem by introducing data structures on the application level and taking all the routine validation tasks. Sometimes a single collection stores multiple models with some discrimination fields to resolve which one to unmarshall documents to.

Having a single stream from multiple collections is the simplest part of the question, [$unionWith](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unionWith/) does exactly that:

```
db.collection1.aggregate( [
   { $unionWith: "collection2" },
   { $sort: { time: 1 } }
] )
```

Unmarshalling of the documents to mongoose models will be a little bit more complex - you will need to do it manually since the documents will have different structure.

Sorting might be a problem tho. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline-operators-and-indexes says the query can benefit from the indexed "time" column as long as there is no $project, $unwind, and $group stages but I would double check it  can be used after $unionWith stage.

It would be much simpler to store the whole websocket stream in a single collection and use it straight from there.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation. After reading this and better understanding the flexibility of MongoDB, I believe the simpler approach is the way to go after all.